# Swift/iOS - Toggle mail on/off in Mail, Contacts and Calendars

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to make a simple app that on button tap it would toggle mail on or off for my work account.

I kind of dont think this is possible at all but would be interested in suggestions of how I could think about making this.

Comment: What do you mean by „mail on/off“ exactly? Can you clarify what that would look like (or what configuration option in in iOS it would behave like)?

Comment: ok so if I were to manually do what I would like this button to do is Settings > Mail > Accounts > iCloud > *toggle mail off*  [ios10]